# Union multiple sp result set with out using temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to merge my multipl sp result set and i cannot use temptable to insert each result into table because my sp also uses insert into statement . So how can i achieve this . This is what i have tried but its not working

```
declare  @SQL varchar(200)
declare @sql2 varchar(200)
declare @sqlresult varchar(200)
set @SQL = 'exec GetCDCDATA ''Employee'' '

set @sql2 = 'exec GetCDCDATA ''EmployeeDATA'' '
set @sqlresult=@SQL+' UNION ALL ' +@sql2
exec SP_executesql @sqlresult
```

Comment: UNION ALL will work only with SELECT statement. It won't works with SPs. You can create UDF instead of SPs if possible then you can use UNION ALL to fetch the data

Comment: Ok , So what is the replacement for sp ? when we have insert command inside sp

Comment: If you have only insert statements in SPs then whar are retriving using UNION ALL?

Comment: I am using temp table inside sp with insert command then i perfome some action on that table and return as resultant table

Comment: Then you have to exexute both the SPs so you have two result sets and then you have to merge both the result set in your coding

Comment: Its not about executing it 2 times it is multiple i don't how many times its going to execute , and are you saying that its not possible in sql ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67453/discussion-between-ancient-and-saharsh-shah).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OpenRowset` to execute your SP.

```
SELECT *
FROM   OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',
                  'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
                  'exec dbname.schemaname.GetCDCDATA ''Employee'' WITH RESULT SETS ((col1 datatype, col2 datatype,...))')
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM   OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',
                  'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
                  'exec dbname.schemaname.GetCDCDATA ''EmployeeDATA'' WITH RESULT SETS ((col1 datatype, col2 datatype,...))')
```

make sure both the SP's return similar number of columns

If you are getting any `error` like

> Msg 7415, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Ad hoc access to OLE DB provider
>   'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' has been denied. You must access this
>   provider through a linked server.

In this case you may have to enable `ad hoc distributed queries`. By default, SQL Server does not allow ad hoc distributed queries using `OPENROWSET`

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Comment: It should be with out temp table mentioned in question

Comment: **SQLNCLI** - `SQL Server Native Client` Is a character string that represents the friendly name (or PROGID) of the OLE DB provider as specified in the registry. Check here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312%28v=sql.100%29.aspx for more info

Comment: Not working Error Summary `Consider using the WITH RESULT SETS clause to explicitly describe the result set.`

Comment: @Ancient Really am not sure about the error but i think it can be fixed by explicitly mentioning the result set of SP like  `'exec dbname.schemaname.GetCDCDATA ''EmployeeDATA'' WITH RESULT SETS ((col1 datatype, col2 datatype))'`

Comment: @Ancient - check here http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/usage-and-benefits-of-using-with-result-sets-in-sql-server-2012.html